# How to show Lottie animation from retrieved JSON

Tags: react-native, lottie

I've used `fetch` to fetch the `.json` file like this:

```
const [jsonRet, setJsonRet] = useState();

    getData = () => {
        fetch('https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/private_files/lf30_GjhcdO.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            console.log('DATA IS: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            setJsonRet(data)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        });
    }

    getData()
```

It prints out `.json` as it should be in a `.json` file otherwise:

[image]

Then I'm displaying it as:

```
<LottieView source={jsonRet} autoPlay loop />
```

The errors I'm getting are:

> Invariant Violation: [77,"LottieAnimationView",21,{"loop":true,"progress":0,"speed":1,"resizeMode":"contain","sourceJson":"{}","onAnimationFinish":true,"onLayout":true,"aspectRatio":"<>","position":"absolute","left":0,"right":0,"top":0,"bottom":0}] is not usable as a native method argument

and

> Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

According to the documentation here, it states that the `source prop is:

*Mandatory - The source of animation. Can be referenced as a local asset by a string, or remotely with an object with a uri property, or it can be an actual JS object of an animation, obtained (for example) with something like `require('../path/to/animation.json')`.*

I've created this snack for anyone to see how to make it work:
https://snack.expo.io/@chtalha/lottie

Comment: are you conditionally rendering the LottieView only when the json exists? my guess is that there may also be an additional issue with dynamically rendering JSON of that size from a state variable, the `field sizes are different` often comes from that sort of thing

Comment: @Kai If you hit this URL `https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json` in any browser it'll give you a JSON. Lottie view requires a JSON and that is exactly what I'm doing. I'm just fetching it and providing it to the component. It's supposed to be as simple as that. I've even tried providing the `data` directly to the `LottieView` but that also didn't work.